# Reversing the elements of an array

Tags: c++, optimization, array

Any way to make this more concise/efficient?

```
// Write a loop that reverses the elements of an array.
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

const int SIZE = 10;

void reverse(int iArrayRef1 []);
void display(int iArrayRef2 []);

int main()
{
    int iArray[SIZE] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };

    // Display in the original order.
    std::cout << "Forwards:\n";
    display(iArray);

    // Reverse the array.
    reverse(iArray);

    std::cout << std::endl;

    // Display in reversed order.
    std::cout << "Backwards:\n";
    display(iArray);
    return 0;
}

void reverse(int iArrayRef1 [])
{
    int temp = 0;
    int* indexPtrBeg = iArrayRef1;
    int* indexPtrEnd = iArrayRef1 += (SIZE-1);

    for (int index = 0; index < (SIZE/2); index++)
    {
        temp = *indexPtrEnd;
        *indexPtrEnd = *indexPtrBeg;
        *indexPtrBeg = temp;
        indexPtrEnd--;
        indexPtrBeg++;
    }
}

void display(int iArrayRef2 [])
{
    for (int index = 0; index < SIZE; index++)
    {
        std::cout << std::setw(2) << iArrayRef2[index] << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: I don't see much wrong. I only wonder why you call the argument ``iArrayRef1`` in ``reverse`` and ``iArrayRef2`` in ``display``. One other minor thing: ``++index`` is slightly faster than ``index++`` since the post-increment operator has to return the pre-incremented value (it first makes a copy, then increments and returns the copy). This also goes for ``indexPtrEnd--`` of course. Modern compilers might optimize the copy away if you don't use it, but it won't hurt to use pre-increment when possible.

Comment: Thank you! In regards to the parameter list, I am still unsure about how to name similar parameters, is there a convention that people generally stick to?

Comment: There's nothing against using the same name in both functions. Personally, all of my function arguments start with 'a' (``void display( int aArray[] )``) to distinguish them from local variables. Also I don't believe hungarian notation (prepending type information to variable names, in your case ``iArray``, where *i* stands for ``int`` I suppose) is very common in C++. In the end though, naming style is personal and you should pick your own and **stick to it**. Inconsistency is the biggest mistake you can make :).

Comment: @thelamb: Yes, normally Hungarian is discouraged. :-) Starting them with `a` isn't best either, but I don't know if it's discouraged as well.  You also won't really need to worry about "local" naming unless you're dealing with classes (you'll have local *and* member).

Comment: @thelamb: I doubt there is any difference in speed between `++index` and `index++`. With built-in types there will be no difference. And this is also a bad argument to use. The argument you should be using is that the speed is not the same for all types and for user defined types in general it is slower (because of the reason you stated). So for maintenance purposes prefer the prefix version so that if the types change your code is always using the optimum version.

Comment: @thelamb: Use of Hungarian notation has fallen out of favor in most (strongly typed) languages because it does not add information and makes maintenance harder (when you change the types you also need to change the variable names to match). The reason it did not add useful information is mainly historical and because most people do not use it correctly. When used correctly it is a powerful tool. Joel has a famous article on the subject: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Wrong.html

Comment: @Jamal: Using `verbs` is the preferred convention for methods (and usually functions). Because the method is an action (hence verb) you are performing on the object.

Comment: @LokiAstari: I see.  I do remember someone else telling me that `aObject` isn't preferred, unless that's a bit different here.

Comment: If you are just reversing for the print. You shoudl consider using iterators. You can print one way with the normal iterators. Then print in reverse using the reverse iterator on the same container. Thus not requiring you to actually reverse the array.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For an implementation without the STL, this is pretty good.  There's no risky memory-management going on with the raw pointers, and your sorting isn't needlessly slow (compared to bubble sort).  I'll base my review on the STL anyway (for future reference), along with some other general tips.

---

- <s>`SIZE` should be of type [`std::size_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t).  It's preferred to use an unsigned integer type for sizes, plus you'll have a larger range (no negative values are part of it).</s>
- If you have C++11, prefer [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) (or any other STL container) over C-style arrays.  This also makes it needless to pass the array size since STL containers already know their own.

  Your array initialization, for instance, would look like this:

  ```
  std::array<int, SIZE> iArray = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
  ```

  If you use the above array or another STL container, the loop counters in `reverse()` and `display()` should be of type [`std::size_type`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/size).  This will ensure:

  1. the supported size type for this container is used
  2. the loop will be able to access any number of elements

  Also, as @thelamb mentioned, pre-increment (`++index`) is preferred because it will avoid extra copies.  This is especially important for user-defined types (such as `std::array`), while post-increment is still okay with native types (such as `int`).
- Prefer *iterators* to raw pointers in C++:

  ```
  // with C++11

  auto begin = std::begin(container);
  auto end   = std::end(container);
  ```

  ```
  // without C++11

  std::ContainerType::iterator begin = std::begin(container);
  std::ContainerType::iterator end   = std::end(container);
  ```
- You could compare your reverse algorithm to the [idiomatic STL method](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse) with regards to efficiency (if you were to perform a speed test on them):

  ```
  std::reverse(container.begin(), container.end());
  ```
- I'd avoid the extra newlines in `display()`.  The function's purpose is solely to display the array, plus you'll be forced to have the newline with each call.  Two things for this:

  1. add the newlines before and/or after the function call instead
  2. use `\n` instead of [`std::endl`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/endl) (the latter *also* flushes the buffer, which takes longer)

  So, instead of this:

  ```
  std::cout << std::endl;

  std::cout << "Backwards:\n";
  display(iArray);
  ```

  you could have this:

  ```
  std::cout << "\nBackwards:\n"; // another '\n' at the front
  display(iArray);
  std::cout << "\n";             // newline here instead of in display()
  ```

---

For comparison, here's an idiomatic alternative using `template`s (any element type is supported).  It uses an [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead of an array, saving you size constraints.  It also displays the vector in [forward](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) and in [reverse](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse_copy) using an [iterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/ostream_iterator), instead of mutating it for the reverse.

```
#include <algorithm> // std::copy, std::reverse_copy
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>  // std::ostream_iterator
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
void displayForward(std::vector<T> const& vec)
{
    std::copy(vec.cbegin(), vec.cend(),
        std::ostream_iterator<T>(std::cout, " "));
}

template <typename T>
void displayReverse(std::vector<T> const& vec)
{
    std::reverse_copy(vec.cbegin(), vec.cend(),
        std::ostream_iterator<T>(std::cout, " "));
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> vec = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };

    std::cout << "Forward:\n";
    displayForward(vec);

    std::cout << "\nBackwards:\n";
    displayReverse(vec);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jamal! I am familiar with the STL std::array, in my class however my teacher requested we use the c-style arrays. If given the choice though, would it be better to use a std::array or a std::vector/std::list?

Comment: Oh, okay.  I didn't know that.  Anyway, that depends on how you will use your data.  If you just need something like a C-style array (static, not dynamic), then choose `std::array`.  If you need to use a dynamically-allocated array (allowing you to add/remove elements from the back), choose `std::vector`.  If you're using a linked list (allowing you to add/remove elements anywhere, albeit possibly slowly), choose `std::list`.  Also note that `std::list` specifically implements a doubly linked-list.

Comment: As for your implementation with disregard to the STL, I think it's okay.  There's not much else you can do with C-style arrays and raw pointers.  The code still compiles, displays the correct results, and looks clean.  I'll add a few more things here.

Comment: Thank you again Jamal. I appreciated the continued guidance.

Comment: @ao2130: You're welcome.  I think you're doing well overall, at least from an academic perspective (if you weren't, then you would've still been using bubble sort). ;-)

Comment: You can also pass an array by reference. `void func(T (&param)[Size])`. Useful when used in combination with templates.

Comment: If you're stuck with C-style arrays but can still use the STL and have access to C++11 then you can use std::begin(array) and std::end(array) to use STL algorithms on C-style arrays.

Answer (score 7):

Don't declare an array with a specific size if you are also going to initialize it:

> ```
> int iArray[SIZE] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
> ```

If SIZE is too small them you have an error (that is not reported). If SIZE is too large then the array is silently filled with 0. Both can be an issue. Prefer:

```
// Let the compiler work out the size from the data you provide.
int iArray[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
```

Though it looks like you are passing an array here:

> ```
> void display(int iArrayRef2 [])
> ```

Its not. You are just passing a pointer (arrays decay to pointers). All array context is lost. This is dangerous as some people forget and try and use `iArrayRef2` as if it was an array. So when you declare a function like this prefer to use pointer syntax. This will remind people that they are dealing with pointers.

```
void display(int* iArrayRef2)
```

Passing an array as a pointer without a size is a bad idea. You have no idea where it ends. Always pass size information. There are a couple of ways to do this:

```
void display(int* iArrayRef2, int size)     // Standard C way
void display(int* begin,      int* end)     // Standard C++ 03 way (iterator based)

// Or do it so you can allow real templates
template<typename I>
void display(I begin, I end)

// Or pass by reference
template<int size>
void display(int (&iArrayRef2)[size])

// Or pass any of the standard containers.
```

Note if you use the template version above:

```
display(&iArray[0],  &iArray[SIZE]);   // prints forward
display(std::reverse_iterator<int*>(&iArray[SIZE]), std::reverse_iterator<int*>(&iArray[0])); // prints backwards
```

You don't need to re-invent swap

```
    temp = *indexPtrEnd;
    *indexPtrEnd = *indexPtrBeg;
    *indexPtrBeg = temp;

    // or
    std::swap(*indexPtrBeg, *indexPtrEnd);
```

If you do encapsulate it in its own function. This will make reading the code easier.

Prefer to use std::reverse rather than your own version (its highly optimized).

There are some useful standard algorithms that can make the code shorter and more readable.

```
for (int index = 0; index < SIZE; index++)
{
    std::cout << std::setw(2) << iArrayRef2[index] << " ";
}

// or
std::cout << std::setw(2);
std::copy(&iArrayRef2[0], &iArrayRef2[SIZE], std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
```

Example of passing an array by reference:

```
template<typename T, int size>
int size(T (&array)[size])
{
      return size;
}
int main()
{
      int   a[10];
      float b[14];
      std::cout << size(a) << " " << size(b) << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I'll just focus on your `reverse()` function, assuming that you want to keep the C-style interface rather than the C++-style `std::array` suggested by @Jamal.  (It's an excellent suggestion, but I just want to focus on some basic ideas for this review.)

I would prefer to have the array size passed in explicitly, rather than relying on the `SIZE` constant.  That way, you can pull the `SIZE` constant into `main()` rather than having it be global.

In `int* indexPtrEnd = iArrayRef1 += (SIZE-1)`, the `+=` is weird.  Just `+` is sufficient; reassigning `iArrayRef1` as a side-effect is confusing (but luckily harmless).

Since you already have two pointers crawling along the array in opposite directions, there is no need to introduce an `index` variable.  You can just terminate the loop when `indexPtrBeg` and `indexPtrEnd` meet or cross each other.

I find your variable names cumbersome.  How about `array`, `begin`, and `end`?  (In `indexPtrBeg`, `index...` is just misleading, and `...Ptr...` stinks of Hungarian notation.)  The `temp` variable is only used within the loop, so you should declare it inside the loop.

```
#include <sys/types.h>   /* for size_t */

void reverse(int array[], size_t size) {
    for (int *begin = array, *end = array + size - 1; begin < end; ++begin, --end) {
        // You could use std::swap() from #include <algorithm>
        // std::swap(*begin, *end);
        int swap = *end;
        *end = *begin;
        *begin = swap;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 good stuff.  It's also nice having STL and non/STL reviews to consider. :-) I do have some notes. 1.) It seems that `SIZE` could still be global since it's used in more than one function. 2.) I would argue that the OP's incrementing and decrementing in `reverse()` is more readable.  They do work in your example, but they seem to bloat that top line.  That may just be me, though.

Answer (score 1):

since this is int reversing, you could avoid the pointers and temp values

(saves memory space, which in this case is not so important but this math trick might help you in the future)

and just use subtraction and adding

for example:

```
int a= 13;
int b= 25;
a=a+b;//38
b=a-b;//38-25 = 13
a=a-b;//38-13 = 25
```

all you have to do is take an array of size x

and you reverse the values of the First(0 index) and last(x-1 index)

then the second (1 index) and one before the last(x-2 index)

and so on

EDIT:

here is my solution using this math trick:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

const int SIZE = 10;

void reverse(int array[])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE/2; i++)
    {
        array[i]+=array[SIZE-(i+1)];
        array[SIZE-(i+1)]=array[i]-array[SIZE-(i+1)];
        array[i]-=array[SIZE-(i+1)];
    }
}

void display(int iArrayRef2 [])
{
    for (int index = 0; index < SIZE; index++)
    {
        std::cout << std::setw(2) << iArrayRef2[index] << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int iArray[SIZE] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,10 };

    // Display in the original order.
    std::cout << "Forwards:\n";
    display(iArray);

    // Reverse the array.
    reverse(iArray);

    std::cout << std::endl;

    // Display in reversed order.
    std::cout << "Backwards:\n";
    display(iArray);

    return 0;

}
```